# iOS 5.0.1: SpringBoard crashed after touching the push notification banner

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, push, springboard

I specified a custom sound about **20 seconds** of my application push. When the push sound had been played for a long time (more than 15 seconds), I touched the banner of push notification, and the **Springboard crashed**.(Alert Style was set to Banners).Anybody have the same issues?

*The crash log:*

```
Incident Identifier: 8D33AEED-3E96-4044-83B0-5CCB5414DBF8
CrashReporter Key:   1da253ef56af792d16752cd9b8dfe668565d7c3f
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         SpringBoard [917]
Path:            /System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
Identifier:      SpringBoard
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-02-20 17:18:49.160 +0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34695fbc 0x34692000 + 16316
1   SpringBoard                     0x0020f73e 0xb0000 + 1439550
2   UIKit                           0x378f5f00 0x377f1000 + 1068800
3   UIKit                           0x37887c16 0x377f1000 + 617494
4   UIKit                           0x37ab3502 0x377f1000 + 2893058
5   UIKit                           0x37802d62 0x377f1000 + 73058
6   UIKit                           0x378018b0 0x377f1000 + 67760
7   UIKit                           0x3780e3c6 0x377f1000 + 119750
8   UIKit                           0x3780e208 0x377f1000 + 119304
9   UIKit                           0x3780ddd6 0x377f1000 + 118230
10  UIKit                           0x377f44e6 0x377f1000 + 13542
11  UIKit                           0x377f3d26 0x377f1000 + 11558
12  GraphicsServices                0x30c26dec 0x30c22000 + 19948
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3441f54c 0x34392000 + 578892
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3441f4ee 0x34392000 + 578798
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3441e33c 0x34392000 + 574268
16  CoreFoundation                  0x343a14d6 0x34392000 + 62678
17  CoreFoundation                  0x343a139e 0x34392000 + 62366
18  GraphicsServices                0x30c25fc6 0x30c22000 + 16326
19  UIKit                           0x3782273c 0x377f1000 + 202556
20  SpringBoard                     0x000b3a2c 0xb0000 + 14892
21  SpringBoard                     0x000b306c 0xb0000 + 12396
```

Answer (score 1):

We are facing the same issue as well on IOS 5.0.1 on only IPod Touches. Works fine on iPhone and iPad.