# Why do I get a leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, instruments, gamekit

I have an app that only contains this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Authenticate Local GameCenter player
    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
     {
         [GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *matches, NSError *error)
          {

          }];
     }];
}
```

And right away, I get a ton of leaks. Am I doing something wrong? I use ARC.

[image]

Comment: looks like its coming from a library you are using, not much you can do about that i dont think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The leak in `loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:` method of `GKTurnBasedMatch` was a known issue in iOS 6.0.1, [which has been fixed in iOS 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14561526/335858).

P.S. The `authenticateWithCompletionHandler:` method is deprecated in iOS 6, but it is not responsible for the leak.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I changed the "Based SDK" to 6.1 and the leaks is gone. But if I have the base SDK set to 6.1, that would limit the people that can download the app right? No 6.0 to <6.1 could  download it?

Comment: @user1251004 This is correct. Since the leak is not in your app but in Apple's code, however, there is little you can do about it. I would keep the base SDK at 6.0, because the leak is not that large, and is also non-repetitive (i.e. it happens only once per successful authentication, not once per minute).