# App crash after click on notification

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ipod-touch

I got crash if application is not in background state and then click on notification. There is no memory leak and set architectures standard (armv6,armv7,armv7s).also referred link

[Springboard crash when app is restored from push notification from GameCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561526/springboard-crash-when-app-is-restored-from-push-notification-from-gamecenter)

Any suggestion to find out solution.Thanks in Advance.

Device Log as below:

```
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000024
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libdispatch.dylib               0x3936b332 0x3936a000 + 4914
1   CropAndGuess                    0x000a92c0 0xa1000 + 33472
2   CropAndGuess                    0x000a6252 0xa1000 + 21074
3   CropAndGuess                    0x000a551a 0xa1000 + 17690
4   UIKit                           0x3313ead4 0x330db000 + 408276
5   UIKit                           0x3313e65e 0x330db000 + 407134
6   UIKit                           0x33136846 0x330db000 + 374854
7   UIKit                           0x330dec34 0x330db000 + 15412
8   UIKit                           0x330de6c8 0x330db000 + 14024
9   UIKit                           0x330de116 0x330db000 + 12566
10  GraphicsServices                0x34dd05a0 0x34dca000 + 26016
11  CoreFoundation                  0x312ab680 0x31214000 + 620160
12  CoreFoundation                  0x312aaee4 0x31214000 + 618212
13  CoreFoundation                  0x312a9cb2 0x31214000 + 613554
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3121ceb8 0x31214000 + 36536
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3121cd44 0x31214000 + 36164
16  UIKit                           0x33135480 0x330db000 + 369792
17  UIKit                           0x331322fc 0x330db000 + 357116
18  CropAndGuess                    0x000a3bbc 0xa1000 + 11196
19  CropAndGuess                    0x000a3b54 0xa1000 + 11092

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39452d98 0x39441000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x393a0cf6 0x3939a000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x393a0a12 0x3939a000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x393a08a0 0x3939a000 + 26784

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39442648 0x39441000 + 5704
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3937b4ec 0x3936a000 + 70892
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3936ddf4 0x3936a000 + 15860

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39452d98 0x39441000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x393a0cf6 0x3939a000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x393a0a12 0x3939a000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x393a08a0 0x3939a000 + 26784

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39441eb4 0x39441000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39442048 0x39441000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x312ab040 0x31214000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                  0x312a9d9e 0x31214000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3121ceb8 0x31214000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3121cd44 0x31214000 + 36164
6   WebCore                         0x3720a500 0x37200000 + 42240
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x393ab30e 0x3939a000 + 70414
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x393ab1d4 0x3939a000 + 70100

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x1fdaab50      r2: 0x3936c115      r3: 0x1fdaab50
    r4: 0x3aefd06c    r5: 0x0015a854      r6: 0x00153828      r7: 0x2fd5e4e8
    r8: 0x00000001    r9: 0x0000007f     r10: 0x38f4f5a1     r11: 0x001538d4
    ip: 0x3aefe7f4    sp: 0x2fd5e4b4      lr: 0x000a92c5      pc: 0x3936b332
  cpsr: 0x20000030
```

Comment: Please Symbolize your crash log, with what you have posted it is not possible to say what has happened.

Comment: Or just run it while having breakpoints on - much simpler. You can read here how to add exception breakpoint: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: I symbolized log and got the method,crash fixed.